Why does the definition of limit imply these two facts in the result on the limit of measurable functions in Measure, Integration & Real Analysis?
I have two potentially related questions concerning limits. I'm reading 2.48 in Measure, Integration & Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler, which is reproduced below.

Why does the definition of limit imply that there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f_k(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$ for all $k \geq m$? I know the definition of the limit of a sequence but am having trouble using it to clarify this implication.

In the proof of the inclusion in the other direction, why is it $f(x) \geq a + \frac{1}{j}$ and not $f(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$ when taking the limit as $k \to \infty$?


I know these are basic but I've tried fiddling with these facts for a bit of time and am still unsure of my reasoning. Thanks in advance for considering my question!

2.48 Limit of $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions. Suppose $(X, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space and $f_1, f_2, \dots$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x)$ exists for each $x \in X$. Define $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x).
$$
Then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.
Proof. Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We will show that
$$
f^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty} f_k^{-1}\left(\left(a + \frac{1}{j}, \infty\right)\right),\quad\quad 2.49
$$
which implies that $f^{-1}((a, \infty)) \in \mathcal{S}$.
To prove 2.49, first suppose $x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))$. Thus there exists $j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$. The definition of limit now implies that there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f_k(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$ for all $k \geq m$. Thus $x$ is in the right side of 2.49, proving that the left side of 2.49 is contained in the right side.
To prove the inclusion in the other direction, suppose $x$ is in the right side of 2.49. Thus there exist $j, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f_k(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$ for all $k \geq m$. Taking the limit as $k \to \infty$, we see that $f(x) \geq a + \frac{1}{j} > a$. Thus $x$ is in the left side of 2.49, completing the proof of 2.49. Thus $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.


(a) If $c_n\to c$ and $c>d$ then choose $\varepsilon=c-d>0$. Eventually, $|c_n-c|<\varepsilon$ so $c_n>c-\varepsilon=d$. (b) If $c_n\to c$ and $c_n>u$ for all $n$ you can only conclude $c\geq u$ in general - example: $u=0,c_n=1/n$.

For the other part of the question, note that you can let $a_k:= f_k(x)$ to see that it is basically a sequence, and if a sequence converges, then it is Cauchy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence). This then implies that we can pick any interval around $f(x)$ (that hasn't got $f(x)$ as end point) and guarantee that the sequence will eventually stay in that interval

Answering my own question :-)

By the definition of the limit of a sequence, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that
$$ \|f_k(x)-f(x)\|_\infty<\varepsilon$$
for every integer $k\geq m$. Thus $f_k(x)>f(x)-\varepsilon$. Now, we know that $f(x)-\left(a+\frac{1}{j}\right)=\delta>0.$ With $\varepsilon=\frac{\delta}{2},$ we have
$$f_k(x)>\left(a+\frac{1}{j}+\delta\right)-\frac{\delta}{2}>a+\frac{1}{j},$$
as desired.

As noted by @Snoop, the strict inequality doesn't hold in the limit in general. As an example, consider $$f_k(x)=a+\frac{1}{j}+\frac{1}{k}.$$ Then $f_k(x)>a+\frac{1}{j}$ for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, but $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=a+\frac{1}{j}$. Thus we can only conclude that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)\geq a+\frac{1}{j}$.


